# How to center table in prawn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I have created a table in prawn and wanted to pass the `:position` option by whih is also documented in the manual but it throws off an `Method_missing` error. It seems like this parameter doesnt exist anymore. How can I center a table in prawn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same error. Installing from master on Github fixed the issue.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'prawn', git: 'https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn.git'
```

[Issue thread on Github](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/issues/150)

Comment: Probably good to mention setting a :ref in your Gemfile in case master becomes broken (then your production environment breaks).

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps

```
pdf.table tablename,
    :border_width => 0,
    :font_size => 11,
    :position => :center
```

Comment: Like I said when I try to use that option I get an undefined method error: `Error: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/prawn-0.12.0/lib/prawn/table.rb:125:in `block in initialize': undefined method `position=' for #<Prawn::Table:0x000000056768f8> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: try installing `gem 'prawn-layout'` or try this if the above does not work
`gem 'prawn', :git => "https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn.git"`

Comment: If we are suppose to pointing to that git, how if someday that git was deleted? Is there aren't any other way to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

whether the PDF generation is from a declared class or within the controller
you need to add the following line to your Gemfile

```
gem 'prawn-table', '~> 0.2.1'
```

At the time of writing that is the gem version, this will give you access to the table methods such as position

I used it in this example and it worked

```
def table_items(chart_data, doc)
  table = Prawn::Table.new(table_rows(chart_data), doc, {:header => true})
  table.row(0).font_style = :bold
  table.position = :center
  table.draw
end
```